# Array of objects, updating in one thread and reading in another

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mono, thread-safety

*Simplified the question to give a more clear representation of what I'm actually asking*

I have two threads, call them `A` and `B`. They share one object of type `Foo` which has a field called `Name` and is stored in an array of type `Foo[]` at index `0`. The threads will always access index `0` in a order which is guaranteed by the system already, so there is no race condition of thread `B` getting before thread `A`.

The order is this.

```
 // Thread A
 array[0].Name = "Jason";

 // Thread B
 string theName = array[0].Name
```

As I said this order is already guaranteed, there is *no way for thread B to read the value before thread A*

What I want to ensure is two things:

1. Both threads get the latest object at index 0.
2. Thread `B` always gets the latest value in the .Name field

Marking `Name` as volatile is not an option, as the real objects are a lot more complex and even have custom structs which can't even have the volatile attribute attached to them.

Now, satisfying 1 is easy (always getting the latest object), you can do a .VolatileRead:

```
 // Thread A
 Foo obj = (Foo)Thread.VolatileRead(ref array[0]);
 obj.Name = "Jason";

 // Thread B
 Foo obj = (Foo)Thread.VolatileRead(ref array[0]);
 string theName = obj.Name
```

Or you can insert a memory barrier:

```
 // Thread A
 array[0].Name = "Jason";
 Thread.MemoryBarrier();

 // Thread B
 Thread.MemoryBarrier();
 string theName = array[0].Name
```

So my question is: Is this enough to also satisfy condition 2? That I always get the latest value from the fields of the object I read out? If the object at index `0` has not changed, but the `Name` has. Will doing a `VolatileRead` or a `MemoryBarrier` on index `0` make sure all the fields IN the object at index `0` also get their latest values?

Comment: Why are you using arrays? Look at the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Not using .NET4, to begin with. And the Concurrent stuff, as far as I know, only make guarantees for the content of the collections itself and not for the possible fields/properties of the objects in the collections.

Comment: I don't think volatile would guarantee what you think it would.

Comment: If there is no guarantee that the objects inserted into the array are threadsafe, I'd think you'd have to do some kind of check out check in system. I'd probably implement it by using one of the collections from the Concurrent namespace. Creating a new type which is IDisposable and generic, having a public T Value. Whenever a thread is then done with the item, it would dispose it, at which point you'd allow other threads to read it. Just a thought.

Comment: Another thought is to only allow threadsafe items into a custom collection. You'd just put a generic wrapper around a List<T> or T[] and have a constraint that T is IThreadSafe (which doesn't have any members, but stays as a reminder for you and other developers).

Comment: I think my example was not clear enough, in reality two threads will never operate on the same object as the same time (not even reading or writing). But one object might get operated on by several threads, but it will all be sequential as in first thread0, then thread5, then maybe thread0 again. But they will never read or write from it at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these solutions, `lock` or `volatile` will solve your problem. Because:

1. `volatile` ensures that variables changed by one thread are visible immediately to other threads operating on the same data (i.e. they are not cached) and also that operations on that variable are not reordered. Not really what you need.
2. `lock` ensures that the write / read do not occur simultaneously but **does not guarantee their order**. It depends which thread acquired the lock first, which is non-deterministic.

Therefore, if your flow is:

```
Thread A read Name
Thread A modify Name
Thread B read Name
```

exactly in that order, you will need to enforce it with an event (i.e. `AutoresetEvent` for example):

```
//Thread A
foo[0].Name = "John"; // write value
event.Set(); // signal B that write is completed

//Thread B
event.WaitOne(); // wait for signal
string name = foo[0].Name; // read value
```

This guarantees that thread B does not read the Name variable until A has modified it.

**Edit**: Ok, so you are sure that the above flow is respected. Since you are saying that you cannot declare the fields `volatile`, I recommend the use of `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` to introduce fences that enforce ordering:

```
//Thread A
foo[0].Name = "John"; // write value
Thread.MemoryBarrier();

//Thread B
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
string name = foo[0].Name; // read value
```

For more info, check this document: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: This is not the problem, two threads can not access it at the same time. Ever. I think people are miss-understanding my question and I need to-rewrite it.

Comment: The access will always be sequential, but from two (or possibly more) different threads.

Comment: @thr: From this statement: "Now to be able to guarantee that Thread1 gets new value stored in the Name field of the Foo..." I understand that you need Thread1 to read Name only after Thread0 is done updating it.

Comment: Yeah I sort of think people miss-understood me. Thread1 will ALWAYS access the value of .Name after Thread0 has written it, this is guaranteed by the system already. What I'm worrying about is Thread1 being guaranteed to get the value that Thread0 wrote. There is no race-condition.

Comment: @thr: then all you need is volatile. See what I wrote in point 1 of my answer. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Tudor, I get that marking .Name as volatile would solve that issue. But the objects in question are a lot more complex in the real code, and marking everything as volatile is not a possibility (both due to performance and due to some types being structs which can't be marked as volatile). My question is basically: Will doing a Thread.VolatileRead(ref myObjects[0]) guarantee me that any fields changed on the object at index 0 will also be "refreshed" for the thread doing the volatile read?

Comment: @thr: You can do it with memory fences. Check my answer again.

Comment: Please note that despite MSDN documentation about volatile it *does not* generate full memory barriers.

Comment: Tudor, thank you, I re-edited my question to be more clear. Can you take a look at it again just to verify we understood eachother?

Comment: @thr: Ok, now with this memory fence structure, both your points are fulfilled. The second fence ensures that thread1 reads the most up to date value.

Comment: @thr: A memory fence is definitely sufficient, because it ensures ordering and invalidation for all variables involved, unlike VolatileRead, that only does so for the variable in question.

Comment: @Tudor Is it enough to just put the memory fence on the read? Since all writes are volatile on .NET anyway. I don't see the reason for the MemoryBarrier on writing, since the order of the operation is already guranteed to be Write->Read by the system.

Comment: If indeed you only care about the field Name, then the fence after the write is not necessary.

Comment: @Tudor, and what about if I have more then one field? The thread reading them will not be able to access the currently writing thread allows it anyway, no matter how many fields it has to write to.

Comment: @thr, yes if they are only writes then it's ok with only the second fence. I was just mentioning a more general case, where you might have also reads in the first thread.

Answer (score 0):

Locks will address the problem you have if I understand it correctly. This is because lock generates implicit (full) memory barriers around itself.

You can also use memory barrier explicitly using `Thread.MemoryBarrier`. Read more [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility). Memory barrier effect can be quite hard to notice on x86, but on more relaxed ordering system such as PPC it is often substantial.